# Error while upgrading 23.04 -> 23.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, 23.10

I am getting this message after running `sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop`

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

I removed all 3rd party ppas from /etc/apt/sources.list.d

ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` #no output

ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` #no output

`sudo apt clean && sudo apt update`    #clean

#output from main.log in dist-update

```
2023-11-30 12:44:55,850 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2023-11-30 12:44:55,850 INFO uname information: 'Linux michael-Kubuntu 6.2.0-37-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 30 21:04:52 UTC 2023 x86_64'
2023-11-30 12:44:56,061 INFO apt version: '2.6.0ubuntu0.1'
2023-11-30 12:44:56,061 INFO python version: '3.11.4 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:01:59) [GCC 12.3.0]'
2023-11-30 12:44:56,066 INFO release-upgrader version '23.10.14' started
2023-11-30 12:44:56,073 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2023-11-30 12:44:56,090 INFO screen could not be run
2023-11-30 12:44:56,117 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2023-11-30 12:44:56,126 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2023-11-30 12:44:56,146 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2023-11-30 12:44:58,588 DEBUG lsb-release: 'lunar'
2023-11-30 12:44:58,589 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2023-11-30 12:44:58,589 DEBUG openCache()
2023-11-30 12:44:58,589 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2023-11-30 12:44:58,589 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2023-11-30 12:44:58,948 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-36 with 
2023-11-30 12:44:58,948 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-37 with 6.2.0-36
2023-11-30 12:44:58,990 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 79130
2023-11-30 12:44:58,990 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'kubuntu-desktop')
2023-11-30 12:44:58,990 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2023-11-30 12:44:58,991 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2023-11-30 12:44:59,923 DEBUG openCache()
2023-11-30 12:45:00,310 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-36 with 
2023-11-30 12:45:00,310 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-37 with 6.2.0-36
2023-11-30 12:45:00,357 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 79130
2023-11-30 12:45:00,357 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2023-11-30 12:45:00,358 DEBUG quirks: running manticPostInitialUpdate
2023-11-30 12:45:00,358 DEBUG running Quirks.manticPostInitialUpdate
2023-11-30 12:45:00,590 DEBUG flatpak will be marked as manually installed
2023-11-30 12:45:00,607 DEBUG gnome-software-plugin-flatpak will be marked as manually installed
2023-11-30 12:45:00,621 INFO cache.commit()
2023-11-30 12:45:03,667 DEBUG Snap authy is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:03,667 DEBUG Snap authy is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:03,931 DEBUG Snap bare is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:03,931 DEBUG Snap bare is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:04,209 DEBUG Snap chromium is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:04,209 DEBUG Snap chromium is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:04,499 DEBUG Snap core18 is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:04,499 DEBUG Snap core18 is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:04,768 DEBUG Snap core22 is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:04,768 DEBUG Snap core22 is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:05,077 DEBUG Snap cups is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:05,077 DEBUG Snap cups is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:05,344 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-28-1804 is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:05,344 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-28-1804 is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:05,610 DEBUG Snap gnome-42-2204 is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:05,906 DEBUG Snap gtk-common-themes is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:06,597 DEBUG Snap snapd is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:06,597 DEBUG Snap snapd is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:06,859 DEBUG Snap teams-for-linux is installed
2023-11-30 12:45:06,859 DEBUG Snap teams-for-linux is not tracking the release channel
2023-11-30 12:45:07,285 DEBUG MetaPkgs: kubuntu-desktop
2023-11-30 12:45:09,429 DEBUG Foreign: 
2023-11-30 12:45:09,429 DEBUG Obsolete: 
2023-11-30 12:45:09,429 DEBUG Have Deb822SourceEntry: True
2023-11-30 12:45:09,430 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2023-11-30 12:45:09,435 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2023-11-30 12:45:09,435 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2023-11-30 12:45:09,435 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2023-11-30 12:45:09,436 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
```

```
2023-11-30 12:45:09,641 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2023-11-30 12:45:31,125 DEBUG openCache()
2023-11-30 12:45:31,477 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-36 with 
2023-11-30 12:45:31,478 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-37 with 6.2.0-36
2023-11-30 12:45:31,515 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 77292
2023-11-30 12:45:31,516 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2023-11-30 12:45:31,516 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2023-11-30 12:45:32,694 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2023-11-30 12:45:32,893 DEBUG Kernel uname: '6.2.0-37-generic' 
2023-11-30 12:45:32,906 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2023-11-30 12:45:33,338 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2023-11-30 12:45:33,338 DEBUG Installing 'baloo-kf5' (kubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeInstall rule)
2023-11-30 12:45:33,338 DEBUG Removing 'powermanagement-interface' (kubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-11-30 12:45:33,338 DEBUG Removing 'guidance-power-manager' (kubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-11-30 12:45:33,339 DEBUG Removing 'kde-guidance-powermanager' (kubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-11-30 12:45:33,339 DEBUG Removing 'kmix' (kubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-11-30 12:45:33,339 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2023-11-30 12:45:33,339 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2023-11-30 12:45:33,411 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-36 with 
2023-11-30 12:45:33,411 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-37 with 6.2.0-36
2023-11-30 12:45:33,411 DEBUG Comparing 6.5.0-13 with 6.2.0-37
2023-11-30 12:45:33,644 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
2023-11-30 12:45:33,647 DEBUG abort called
2023-11-30 12:45:33,648 DEBUG openCache()
2023-11-30 12:45:34,749 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-36 with 
2023-11-30 12:45:34,750 DEBUG Comparing 6.2.0-37 with 6.2.0-36
2023-11-30 12:45:34,804 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 79130
```

Not sure where to go from here and not really wanting to do a fresh install

#apt.log tail end

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 6
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 6
Investigating (0) libfreetype6-dev:amd64 < 2.12.1+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libfreetype6-dev:amd64 Depends on libfreetype-dev:amd64 < 2.12.1+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 -> 2.13.1+dfsg-1 @ii umU > (= 2.12.1+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1)
  Considering libfreetype-dev:amd64 21 as a solution to libfreetype6-dev:amd64 4
  Removing libfreetype6-dev:amd64 rather than change libfreetype-dev:amd64
  MarkDelete libfreetype6-dev:amd64 < 2.12.1+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libavcodec59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavcodec59:amd64 Depends on libswresample4:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 -> 7:6.0-6ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1)
  Considering libswresample4:amd64 47 as a solution to libavcodec59:amd64 1
  Removing libavcodec59:amd64 rather than change libswresample4:amd64
  MarkDelete libavcodec59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libavformat59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavformat59:amd64 Depends on libavcodec59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1)
  Considering libavcodec59:amd64 1 as a solution to libavformat59:amd64 0
  Removing libavformat59:amd64 rather than change libavcodec59:amd64
  MarkDelete libavformat59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libavfilter8:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavfilter8:amd64 Depends on libavcodec59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1)
  Considering libavcodec59:amd64 1 as a solution to libavfilter8:amd64 -1
  Removing libavfilter8:amd64 rather than change libavcodec59:amd64
  MarkDelete libavfilter8:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libc++1:amd64 < 1:15.0-56~exp2 -> 1:16.0-57 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libc++1:amd64 Depends on libc++1-16:amd64 < none | 1:16.0.6-15 @un uH > (>= 16~)
  Considering libc++1-16:amd64 0 as a solution to libc++1:amd64 -1
  MarkKeep libc++1:amd64 < 1:15.0-56~exp2 -> 1:16.0-57 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libc++1:amd64 rather than change libc++1-16:amd64
Investigating (0) libavdevice59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libavdevice59:amd64 Depends on libavcodec59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mR > (= 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1)
  Considering libavcodec59:amd64 1 as a solution to libavdevice59:amd64 -2
  Removing libavdevice59:amd64 rather than change libavcodec59:amd64
  MarkDelete libavdevice59:amd64 < 7:5.1.2-3ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 < 1.28.1+really1.28.0-5build1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 Depends on gnustep-base-common:amd64 < 1.28.1+really1.28.0-5build1 -> 1.29.0-6ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 1.28.1+really1.28.0-5build1)
  Considering gnustep-base-common:amd64 5 as a solution to libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 -2
  Removing libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 rather than change gnustep-base-common:amd64
  MarkDelete libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 < 1.28.1+really1.28.0-5build1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libevent-2.1-7a:amd64 < 2.1.12-stable-8ubuntu3 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libevent-2.1-7a:amd64 Depends on libevent-2.1-7:amd64 < 2.1.12-stable-8ubuntu3 -> 2.1.12-stable-9 @ii umU > (= 2.1.12-stable-8ubuntu3)
  Considering libevent-2.1-7:amd64 18 as a solution to libevent-2.1-7a:amd64 -2
  Removing libevent-2.1-7a:amd64 rather than change libevent-2.1-7:amd64
  MarkDelete libevent-2.1-7a:amd64 < 2.1.12-stable-8ubuntu3 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
 Try to Re-Instate (1) libc++1:amd64
  MarkKeep libc++1:amd64 < 1:15.0-56~exp2 -> 1:16.0-57 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Done
  MarkKeep initramfs-tools-core:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 -> 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii umU > FU=0
  MarkKeep initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 -> 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii umU > FU=0
  MarkKeep initramfs-tools:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 -> 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
Entering ResolveByKeep
  Dependencies are not satisfied for ubuntu-minimal:amd64 < 1.501 -> 1.524 @ii umU Ib >
Keeping package ubuntu-minimal:amd64
  MarkKeep ubuntu-minimal:amd64 < 1.501 -> 1.524 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Dependencies are not satisfied for isc-dhcp-client:amd64 < 4.4.3-P1-1ubuntu1 -> 4.4.3-P1-2ubuntu5 @ii umU Ib >
Keeping package isc-dhcp-client:amd64
  MarkKeep isc-dhcp-client:amd64 < 4.4.3-P1-1ubuntu1 -> 4.4.3-P1-2ubuntu5 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Dependencies are not satisfied for linux-firmware:amd64 < 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.9 -> 20230919.git3672ccab-0ubuntu2.4 @ii umU Ib >
Keeping package linux-firmware:amd64
  MarkKeep linux-firmware:amd64 < 20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.9 -> 20230919.git3672ccab-0ubuntu2.4 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Ignore MarkGarbage of initramfs-tools-core:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii puH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
  Ignore MarkGarbage of firmware-sof-signed:amd64 < 2.2.4+2.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 | 2.2.6-1ubuntu1.2 @ii puH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
None
  MarkInstall ubuntu-minimal:amd64 < 1.501 -> 1.524 @ii umU Ib > FU=1
    Ignore MarkInstall of initramfs-tools:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii pumH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
   Removing: initramfs-tools:amd64 as upgrade is not possible
    Ignore MarkDelete of initramfs-tools:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii pumH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
  Ignore MarkGarbage of initramfs-tools-core:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii puH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
  Ignore MarkGarbage of firmware-sof-signed:amd64 < 2.2.4+2.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 | 2.2.6-1ubuntu1.2 @ii puH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) ubuntu-minimal:amd64 < 1.501 -> 1.524 @ii pumU Ib >
Broken ubuntu-minimal:amd64 Breaks on initramfs-tools:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii pumH > (< 0.142ubuntu9~)
  Considering initramfs-tools:amd64 9 as a solution to ubuntu-minimal:amd64 10003
  Upgrading initramfs-tools:amd64 due to Breaks field in ubuntu-minimal:amd64
  Ignore MarkInstall of initramfs-tools:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii pumH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
Done
  Ignore MarkGarbage of initramfs-tools-core:amd64 < 0.142ubuntu2.2 | 0.142ubuntu15.1 @ii puH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
  Ignore MarkGarbage of firmware-sof-signed:amd64 < 2.2.4+2.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 | 2.2.6-1ubuntu1.2 @ii puH > as its mode (Keep) is protected
Log time: 2023-11-30 12:45:34.788424
```

Comment: From your output: `E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` This means that you have installed non-Ubuntu or wrong-version software packages that conflict with Ubuntu 23.10. Locate and uninstall those packages. Context: This is the #1 cause, by far, of failed release-upgrades and is almost always self-inflicted. Kudos: You were very wise to read the output and locate your log! Great job! You are already well down the path to fixing it.

Comment: dpkg --get-selections | grep hold output yields nothing as far as held packages and same goes for sudo dpkg --configure -a there arent any errors listed in the logs except for the generic one E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: What about `apt.log` ?

Comment: Added the end portion starting with Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 6
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 6 

to the end of this post. Does this look like these 6 packages are the culprits?

Comment: Is snapd.service and snapd.socket running?

Comment: Output for snapt status

○ → sudo systemctl status snapd
[sudo] password for michael: 
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-11-30 12:47:31 EST; 5h 54min ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 2242 (snapd)
      Tasks: 39 (limit: 76883)
     Memory: 398.9M
        CPU: 15.152s
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─2242 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Comment: Wrong Idea from me.

Comment: Got this working by removing all 3rd party debian packages from apt sources + updating snaps manually and waiting a day or so for apt updates to appear successfully upgraded to 23.10 today